# Polymer and TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have been trying without success implement a web component integrating Polymer and TypeScript.
Does anyone knows where can I see a sample?
Is there an alternative to Polymer?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I came up with a solution... maybe not the best solution but at least kind of working solution. Still need to investigate deeper on this.

the custom element HTML:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>

<polymer-element name="my-element" constructor="MyElement5">
    <template>
        <span id="el"></span>
    </template>
    <script src="my-element.js"/>

</polymer-element>
```

my typescript file (my-element.ts):

```
class Owner{
    ownerinfo:string;
    constructor(public firstName:string, public age:number){
        this.ownerinfo = firstName + " " + age + " yo";
    }

}

var polymer = window['Polymer'];
polymer('my-element',{
    owner:new Owner('TheOwner', 100),
    ready:function(){
        this.$.el.textContent = this.owner.ownerinfo;
    }
})
```

and finally, the javascript generated by TypeScript:

```
var Owner = (function () {
    function Owner(firstName, age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.age = age;
        this.ownerinfo = firstName + " " + age + " yo";
    }
    return Owner;
})();

var polymer = window['Polymer'];
polymer('my-element', {
    owner: new Owner('TheOwner', 100),
    ready: function () {
        this.$.el.textContent = this.owner.ownerinfo;
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=my-element.js.map
```

And with this it works and I can even debug in Firefox or Chrome.
Let's see if I come with some step back on this... 
Hope this helps other guys.

At the end I was thinking too much... and forgot the most important: TypeScript is JavaScript LoL

== almost forgot my Pyramid template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="${request.static_url('my_project:static/polymer/bower_components/platform/platform.js')}"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom webcomponents -->
    <link rel="import" href="${request.static_url('my_project:static/webcomponents/my-element.html')}"/>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${request.static_url('my_project:static/theme.css')}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<!-- My Super Custom WebComponent -->
<my-element></my-element>
<script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Awesome... Polymer + TypeScript + Python

Comment: Consider also adding a polymer.d.ts file so that you don't need to do the `var polymer = window['Polymer'];` business. For example: `var Polymer : (name:string, attributes?:{[fieldName: string]: any})=>void;`

Comment: Consider using the --noImplicitAny flag to tsc-- As @PeterBurns was pointing out, var polymer = window['Polymer']; ends up with polymer being of type any, which gives you no type protection whatsoever. Even if you don't want to fully type all of Polymer, starting with a basic Polymer interface that you add on as you go would be a great start.